# Xpath xslt to check 2 conditions belong 2 elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have 1 xml file. I need to keep all the elements of origin xml and just modify the @MODEL = MD4A in case @Model = MD04 and CHARACTERISTIC/text() = T023

But my 2nd condition not worked. I think it relate to xpath. Can somebody helps me on this.
Thanks so much

```
<DESCRIPTOR xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="MOM.Production" XSDVER="1.0.0.0" MSG_ID="A3D45493-7DD3-48F9-B950-5903A9681091" PRODUCTIONORDER="0001">
  <POSECTION LOCATION="" MODEL="MD04" ERPORDER="0001" />
  <CHARACTERISTICSSECTION>
    <CHARACTERISTIC CHAR_ID="T02" CHAR_DESCR="DRIVETRAIN ">T023</CHARACTERISTIC>
    <CHARACTERISTIC CHAR_ID="T10" CHAR_DESCR="TAILLAMP ">T102</CHARACTERISTIC>
</CHARACTERISTICSSECTION>
</DESCRIPTOR>
```

And here my xslt

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"           xmlns:ns="MOM.Production">
<xsl:template match="ns:MES_VEHICLE_STATUS_DESCRIPTOR/ns:POSECTION/@LOCATION" />
<xsl:template match="ns:MES_VEHICLE_STATUS_DESCRIPTOR/ns:POSECTION/@ERPORDER" />
<xsl:template match="ns:MES_VEHICLE_STATUS_DESCRIPTOR/ns:POSECTION/@MODEL" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>                                                                                                                                   
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="ns:POSECTION/@MODEL">
    <xsl:attribute name="MODEL">
    <xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test=" . = 'MD04' and /CHARACTERISTICSSECTION/CHARACTERISTIC/text() = 'T023'">                                                                  <xsl:text>MD4A</xsl:text>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

(updated)My expectation: MODEL="MD4A" instead of MD04

```
<DESCRIPTOR xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="MOM.Production"
            XSDVER="1.0.0.0"
            MSG_ID="A3D45493-7DD3-48F9-B950-5903A9681091"
            PRODUCTIONORDER="0001">
  <POSECTION LOCATION="" MODEL="MD4A" ERPORDER="0001"/>
  <CHARACTERISTICSSECTION>
      <CHARACTERISTIC CHAR_ID="T02" CHAR_DESCR="DRIVETRAIN ">T023</CHARACTERISTIC>
      <CHARACTERISTIC CHAR_ID="T10" CHAR_DESCR="TAILLAMP ">T102</CHARACTERISTIC>
   </CHARACTERISTICSSECTION>
</DESCRIPTOR>
```

Comment: Please explain better which modification you want to perform on which nodes, for instance, by showing the desired result for the input sample you posted.

Comment: I updated my expectation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if you want to keep most stuff, start with the identity transformation template

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

then add a template matching each node that needs a change e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="ns:POSECTION/@MODEL[. = 'MD04' and ../../ns:CHARACTERISTICSSECTION/ns:CHARACTERISTIC = 'T023']">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">MD4A</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi. I tried with your and seem ../ns:CHARACTERISTICSSECTION/ns:CHARACTERISTIC = 'T023' still not work

Comment: @DangHai, I have corrected a typo in the second sample and corrected the path to use two `..` as we need to look up from the attribute node to the grandparent element node.